# How to optimize for inference a simple, saved TensorFlow 1.0.1 graph?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I cannot successfully run the `optimize_for_inference` module on a simple, saved TensorFlow graph (Python 2.7; package installed by `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.0.1`).

## Background

### Saving TensorFlow Graph

Here's my Python script to generate and save a simple graph to add 5 to my input `x` `placeholder` operation.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# make and save a simple graph
G = tf.Graph()
with G.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(), name="x")
    a = tf.Variable(5.0, name="a")
    y = tf.add(a, x, name="y")
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=G) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    out = sess.run(fetches=[y], feed_dict={x: 1.0})
    print(out)
    saver.save(sess=sess, save_path="test_model")
```

### Restoring TensorFlow Graph

I have a simple restore script that recreates the saved graph and restores graph params. Both the save/restore scripts produce the same output.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Restore simple graph and test model output
G = tf.Graph()

with tf.Session(graph=G) as sess:
    # recreate saved graph (structure)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./test_model.meta')
    # restore net params
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))

    x = G.get_operation_by_name("x").outputs[0]
    y = G.get_operation_by_name("y").outputs
    out = sess.run(fetches=[y], feed_dict={x: 1.0})
    print(out[0])
```

### Optimization Attempt

But, while I don't expect much in terms of optimization, when I try to optimize the graph for inference, I get the following error message. The expected output node does not appear to be in the saved graph.

```
$ python -m tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference --input test_model.data-00000-of-00001 --output opt_model --input_names=x --output_names=y  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main  
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code  
    exec code in run_globals  
  File "/{path}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py", line 141, in <module>  
    app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)  
  File "/{path}/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run  
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/{path}/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py", line 90, in main  
    FLAGS.output_names.split(","), FLAGS.placeholder_type_enum)  
  File "/{path}/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference_lib.py", line 91, in optimize_for_inference  
    placeholder_type_enum)  
  File "/{path}/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/tools/strip_unused_lib.py", line 71, in strip_unused  
    output_node_names)  
  File "/{path}/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py", line 141, in extract_sub_graph  
    assert d in name_to_node_map, "%s is not in graph" % d  
AssertionError: y is not in graph
```

Further investigation led me to inspect the checkpoint of the saved graph, which only shows 1 tensor (`a`, no `x` and no `y`).

```
(tf-1.0.1) $ python -m tensorflow.python.tools.inspect_checkpoint --file_name ./test_model --all_tensors
tensor_name:  a
5.0
```

## Specific Questions

1. Why do I not see `x` and `y` in the checkpoint? Is it because they are operations and not tensors?
2. Since I need to provide input and output names to the `optimize_for_inference` module, how do I build the graph so I can reference the input and output nodes?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Here is the detailed guide on how to optimize for inference:**

The `optimize_for_inference` module takes a `frozen binary GraphDef` file as input and outputs the `optimized Graph Def` file which you can use for inference. And to get the `frozen binary GraphDef file` you need to use the module `freeze_graph` which takes a `GraphDef proto`, a `SaverDef proto` and a set of variables stored in a checkpoint file. The steps to achieve that is given below:

## 1. Saving tensorflow graph

```
 # make and save a simple graph
 G = tf.Graph()
 with G.as_default():
   x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(), name="x")
   a = tf.Variable(5.0, name="a")
   y = tf.add(a, x, name="y")
   saver = tf.train.Saver()

with tf.Session(graph=G) as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
   out = sess.run(fetches=[y], feed_dict={x: 1.0})

  # Save GraphDef
  tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def,'.','graph.pb')
  # Save checkpoint
  saver.save(sess=sess, save_path="test_model")
```

## 2. Freeze graph

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.freeze_graph --input_graph graph.pb --input_checkpoint test_model --output_graph graph_frozen.pb --output_node_names=y
```

## 3. Optimize for inference

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference --input graph_frozen.pb --output graph_optimized.pb --input_names=x --output_names=y
```

## 4. Using Optimized graph

```
with tf.gfile.GFile('graph_optimized.pb', 'rb') as f:
   graph_def_optimized = tf.GraphDef()
   graph_def_optimized.ParseFromString(f.read())

G = tf.Graph()

with tf.Session(graph=G) as sess:
    y, = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def_optimized, return_elements=['y:0'])
    print('Operations in Optimized Graph:')
    print([op.name for op in G.get_operations()])
    x = G.get_tensor_by_name('import/x:0')
    out = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: 1.0})
    print(out)

#Output
#Operations in Optimized Graph:
#['import/x', 'import/a', 'import/y']
#6.0
```

## 5. For multiple output names

If there are multiple output nodes, then specify : `output_node_names = 'boxes, scores, classes'` and import graph by,

```
 boxes,scores,classes, = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def_optimized, return_elements=['boxes:0', 'scores:0', 'classes:0'])
```

Comment: This is a very helpful, constructive and detailed answer. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent answer! Your comments were invaluable as I didn't realize you had to save the graph and checkpoint separately. BTW, I did have to change `--input_checkpoint test_model` to `--input_checkpoint ./test_model` to get `freeze_graph` to work.

Comment: @vijaym How can I specify if I have multiple outputs -- --output_names='cat','shape'   This is not working.

Comment: Why the need to call `global_variables_initializer.run` though for a frozen graph?

Comment: @user1050619 To specify multiple output : `--output_names='cat,shape'`.

Note that there is no space after the coma

Comment: Excellent, nice, perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

1. You are doing it wrong: `input` is a graphdef file for the [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference.py) not the data part of the checkpoint. You need to freeze the model to a `.pb` file/ or get the prototxt for graph and use the optimize for inference script.

`This script takes either a frozen binary GraphDef file (where the weight
variables have been converted into constants by the freeze_graph script), or a
text GraphDef proto file (the weight variables are stored in a separate
checkpoint file), and outputs a new GraphDef with the optimizations applied.`

2. Get the graph proto file using [write_graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/write_graph)
3. get the frozen model [freeze graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py)