# Inference optimization for multiple inputs/outputs custom Estimator

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, tensorflow-estimator, inference

I have a custom Estimator. I'm trying to optimize this Estimator for inference (freeze + optimize).

Here is what I tried to add in `model_fn()` :

```
input_tensors = [input_1, input_2, input_3]
output_tensors = [output_1, output_2, output_3, output_4]

tmp_g = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()

from tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference_lib import optimize_for_inference

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    tmp_g = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, tmp_g, [n.name[:-2] for n in output_tensors])
    dtypes = [n.dtype for n in input_tensors]

    tmp_g = optimize_for_inference(
                tmp_g,
                [n.name[:-2] for n in input_tensors],
                [n.name[:-2] for n in output_tensors],
                [dtype.as_datatype_enum for dtype in dtypes],
                False)


    output_1, output_2, output_3, output_4 = tf.import_graph_def(tmp_g, input_map={n.name[:-2] + ':0': n for n in input_tensors}, return_elements=['output_1', 'output_2', 'output_3', 'output_4 '])
    from tensorflow.python.estimator.model_fn import EstimatorSpec

    return EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions={
                "output_1": output_1[0],
                "output_2": output_2[0],
                "output_3": output_3[0],
                "output_4": output_4[0]
        })
```

However, when `import_graph_def` is called, I receive following error :

> ValueError: Node 'bert/embeddings/ExpandDims': Connecting to invalid
>   output 1 of source node IteratorGetNext which has 1 outputs

(My inputs are connected to a BERT model).

---

**Any idea from where it come from ? And how to fix this ?**

Answer (score 1):

The name of my tensors were wrong when I call `tf.import_graph_def`.

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45493657/9494790) for help.

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1m4JbKeAaC0Y1lIGjzmJYNGAeUu1JJVyS) is a minimal example on Colab.

I fixed the problem by doing :

```
output_1, output_2, output_3, output_4 = tf.import_graph_def(tmp_g, input_map={n.name: n for n in input_tensors}, return_elements=[n.name for n in output_tensors])
```